# Enumerations for a game character's statistics

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, enum, role-playing-game

I would like to improve my functions and work properly on enums without all of those IFs as well as make it more consistent (for example `Backgrounds::displayQualifingBackgroundNames()`). How should I go around it properly?

The file I'm reading from looks like this: http://ideone.com/cQ4M3g

I know I'm missing few things when I'm reading from a file, but I'll fix it later. I'm a beginner so this is probably horrible, but it is working.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

const string stats[] = {"Upkeep","ExperienceGain","MeleeSkill","RangeSkill","Resolve","MeleeDefense","RangeDefense","HitPoints","Initiative","ChanceHead","Fatigue"};

string stringLowCase(string s) {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; ++i) {
    if('A' <= s[i] && s[i] <= 'Z') {
      s[i] += 32;
    }
  }
  return s;
}

enum stat {
  UPKEEP, EXPERIENCEGAIN, MELEESKILL, RANGESKILL, RESOLVE, MELEEDEFENSE, RANGEDEFENSE, HITPOINTS, INITIATIVE, CHANCEHEAD, FATIGUE
};

stat stringToENUM(const string & s) {
  if(s == "upkeep") {
    return UPKEEP;
  }
  if(s == "experiencegain") {
    return EXPERIENCEGAIN;
  }
  if(s == "meleeskill") {
    return MELEESKILL;
  }
  if(s == "rangeskill") {
    return RANGESKILL;
  }
  if(s == "resolve") {
    return RESOLVE;
  }
  if(s == "meleedefense") {
    return MELEEDEFENSE;
  }
  if(s == "rangedefense") {
    return RANGEDEFENSE;
  }
  if(s == "hitpoints") {
    return HITPOINTS;
  }
  if(s == "initiative") {
    return INITIATIVE;
  }
  if(s == "chancehead") {
    return CHANCEHEAD;
  }
  if(s == "fatigue") {
    return FATIGUE;
  }
  else {
    cout << "ERROR TO STRING: " << s << endl;
  }
}

stat stringToEnum(const string & s) {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; ++i) {
    if(stringLowCase(stats[i]) == stringLowCase(s)) {
      return stringToENUM(stringLowCase(stats[i]));
    }
  }
}

class Backgrounds {
  static const int statsSize = 11;

  class Background {
    string
    backgroundName;

    int
    upkeep,
    experienceGain,
    meleeSkill,
    rangeSkill,
    resolve,
    meleeDefense,
    rangeDefense,
    hitPoints,
    initiative,
    chanceHead,
    fatigue;

    public:

    Background(const string & backgroundName = "", const int & upkeep = 0, const int & experienceGain = 0, const int & meleeSkill = 0, const int & rangeSkill = 0,
               const int & resolve = 0, const int & meleeDefense = 0, const int & rangeDefense = 0, const int & hitPoints = 0,
               const int & initiative = 0, const int & chanceHead = 0, const int & fatigue = 0)
               : backgroundName(backgroundName), upkeep(upkeep), experienceGain(experienceGain), meleeSkill(meleeSkill), rangeSkill(rangeSkill),
                 resolve(resolve), meleeDefense(meleeDefense), rangeDefense(rangeDefense), hitPoints(hitPoints),
                 initiative(initiative), chanceHead(chanceHead), fatigue(fatigue) {}

    void modify(const stat & statName, const int & value) {
      switch(statName) {
        case UPKEEP: upkeep = value; break;
        case EXPERIENCEGAIN: experienceGain = value; break;
        case MELEESKILL: meleeSkill = value; break;
        case RANGESKILL: rangeSkill = value; break;
        case RESOLVE: resolve = value; break;
        case MELEEDEFENSE: meleeDefense = value; break;
        case RANGEDEFENSE: rangeDefense = value; break;
        case HITPOINTS: hitPoints = value; break;
        case INITIATIVE: initiative = value; break;
        case CHANCEHEAD: chanceHead = value; break;
        case FATIGUE: fatigue = value; break;
        default: cout << "STATNAME: " << statName << backgroundName << " ERROR at modify()! " << endl; break;
      }
    }

    string name() const {
      return backgroundName;
    }

    void displayHelper(const string & statName, const int & value, const bool & percentage = false) const {
      cout << statName << ": ";
      if(value > 0) cout << "+";
      cout << value;
      if(percentage) cout << "%";
      cout << endl;
    }

    void display(const bool & blank = false) const {
      cout << "-------" << endl;
      cout << backgroundName << endl;
      if(upkeep != 0) {
        cout << "Upkeep: " << upkeep << endl;
      }
      if(experienceGain != 0) {
        displayHelper("Experience Gain",experienceGain);
      }
      if(meleeSkill != 0) {
        displayHelper("Melee Skill",meleeSkill);
      }
      if(rangeSkill != 0) {
        displayHelper("Ranged Skill",rangeSkill);
      }
      if(resolve != 0) {
        displayHelper("Resolve",resolve);
      }
      if(meleeDefense != 0) {
        displayHelper("Melee Defense",meleeDefense);
      }
      if(rangeDefense != 0) {
        displayHelper("Ranged Defense",rangeDefense);
      }
      if(hitPoints != 0) {
        displayHelper("Hit Points",hitPoints);
      }
      if(initiative != 0) {
        displayHelper("Initiative",initiative);
      }
      if(chanceHead != 0) {
        displayHelper("Head Hit",chanceHead);
      }
      if(fatigue != 0) {
        displayHelper("Fatigue",fatigue);
      }
      if(!blank) {
        cout << "-------" << endl;
      }
    }

    friend class Backgrounds;
  };

  vector<Background> backgrounds;

  public:

  Backgrounds() : backgrounds(0) {}

  void loadBackgrounds() {
    cout << "Loading" << endl;
    ifstream readfile("backgrounds.txt");
    bool isEmpty = true;
    int current = -1;
    while(true) {
      if(isEmpty) {
        ++current;
        string name;
        getline(readfile,name);
        backgrounds.push_back(Background(name));
//        cout << "Read name: " << name << endl;
        isEmpty = false;
      }
      else {
        int values;
        readfile >> values;
//        cout << "VALUES: " << values << endl;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < values ; ++i) {
          int value;
          string name;
          readfile >> value >> name;
          backgrounds[current].modify(stringToEnum(name), value);
        }
        string emptyLine;
        getline(readfile,emptyLine);
        getline(readfile,emptyLine);
        if(emptyLine == "END") {
          break;
        }
//        backgrounds[current].display();
        isEmpty = true;
      }
//      int aaa;
//      cin >> aaa;
    }
    readfile.close();
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    cout << "Backgrounds loaded: " << size() << endl << endl;
  }

  int size() const {
    return backgrounds.size();
  }

  int find(const string & text) const {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < statsSize ; ++i) {
      if(stringLowCase(stats[i]) == text) {
        return -2;
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size() ; ++i) {
      if(backgrounds[i].name() == text) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  void displayBackground(const int & index) const {
    backgrounds[index].display();
  }

  void displayBackgroundNames() const {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size() ; ++i) {
      cout.width(18);
      cout.left;
      cout << backgrounds[i].name() << " ";
      if((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
        cout << endl;
      }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
  }

  void displayAvailableTags() const {
    cout << "Available tags to search for specific stat:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < statsSize ; ++i) {
      cout << stringLowCase(stats[i]) << " ";
      if((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
        cout << endl;
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  void displayQualifingBackgroundNames(const stat & statName) const {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size() ; ++i) {
      switch(statName) {
        case UPKEEP: if(backgrounds[i].upkeep != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case EXPERIENCEGAIN: if(backgrounds[i].experienceGain != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case MELEESKILL: if(backgrounds[i].meleeSkill != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case RANGESKILL: if(backgrounds[i].rangeSkill != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case RESOLVE: if(backgrounds[i].resolve != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case MELEEDEFENSE: if(backgrounds[i].meleeDefense != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case RANGEDEFENSE: if(backgrounds[i].rangeDefense != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case HITPOINTS: if(backgrounds[i].hitPoints != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case INITIATIVE: if(backgrounds[i].initiative != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case CHANCEHEAD: if(backgrounds[i].chanceHead != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;
        case FATIGUE: if(backgrounds[i].fatigue != 0) { backgrounds[i].display(true); } break;

//        default: cout << "ERROR at displayQualify()! " << endl; break;
      }
    }
  }

};

int main() {
  Backgrounds bg;
  bg.loadBackgrounds();
  bg.displayBackgroundNames();
  bg.displayAvailableTags();
  cout << endl;

  while(true) {
    cout << "Enter a name of a background or a tag: ";
    string text;
    getline(cin,text);
    stringLowCase(text);
    int index = bg.find(text);

    if(index >= 0) {
      system("cls");
      bg.displayBackgroundNames();
      bg.displayAvailableTags();
      bg.displayBackground(index);
    }
    else if(index == -2) {
      system("cls");
      bg.displayQualifingBackgroundNames(stringToEnum(text));
    }
    else {
      system("cls");
      bg.displayBackgroundNames();
      bg.displayAvailableTags();
      cout << "ERROR: Wrong background name" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a question for you. Why do you need an enum? As far as I can tell your logic goes something like this:

1. Read string
2. Make it lower case
3. Convert it to enumeration with a series of `if` comparisons
4. Convert it to a value to modify with a `switch`

Notice steps 3, 4 there are very repetitive. What if we could get our value directly from the string? And make it more efficient than a bunch of equality comparisons? I posit to you that we can.

**Use Maps for Lookup**

Right now, when you read in `fatigue`, you have to compare it against *every other* modifier. And then do a switch on that. Let's use a hashtable instead - it's a far better way of doing lookup. We'll use the lower-case string as our key. What should we use as our value? Let's pick the most direct thing for our use-case: the actual pointers to the values!

```
// private member on Background
static std::unordered_map<std::string, int Background::*> stats_map{
     {"upkeep", &Background::upkeep},
     {"experiencegain", &Background::experienceGain},
     ...
};
```

What can we do with that? So much! Right now you do:

```
backgrounds[current].modify(stringToEnum(name), value);
```

Let's replace that with just:

```
backgrounds[current].modify(name, value);
```

Where `modify()` can now be (both arguments by value):

```
void modify(std::string statName, int value) {
    // to lower case 
    for (char& c : statName) {
        c = tolower(c);
    }

    // look it up
    auto it = stats_map.find(statName);
    if (it != stats_map.end()) {
        // assign as appropriate
        auto member = it->second;
        (this->*member) = value;
    }
    else {
        // error!
    }
}
```

This is less code that is less error prone while also being more efficient.

One other comment I wanted to make is in regards to the...

**Department of Redundancy Department**

You have a helper function, `displayHelper()`, in which you factored out a bunch of common code. This is great. However, as far as I can tell, it is *always* called like this:

```
if (x != 0) {
    displayHelper("foo", x);
}
```

Just move that check inside of `displayHelper`:

```
void displayHelper(const std::string& statName, int value, bool percentage = false) const {
    if (value != 0) {
        std::cout << statName << ": ";
        if(value > 0) std::cout << "+";
        std::cout << value;
        if(percentage) std::cout << "%";
        std::cout << endl;
    }
}
```

so you can write:

```
 displayHelper("Experience Gain", experienceGain);
 displayHelper("Melee Skill", meleeSkill);
 displayHelper("Ranged Skill", rangeSkill);
 ...
```

This directly leads into:

**`using namespace std`;**

Don't do it. Ever. Writing `std::` takes 5 characters. See also [why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2069064)

**Passing by const ref?**

There is no reason to pass fundamental types like `int` or `bool` by reference-to-const. It may actually be more expensive too. Just pass them by value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I guess I'll search for more informations regarding passing by const reference because that's what I've been told is the quickest way to pass read-only value. Thanks for point out the part about using namespace std - I'll go and read it!